# Mixing class and instance variables together

Tags: python, class, variables, python-3.x, instance

I'm designing a simple role-playing game (similar to World of Warcraft, League of Legends, etc.) where you basically have a hero or a champion who fights with wild creatures and other heroes/champions.
This hero can then level up by gaining experience points from fights, and each level grants him a *skill point*, which allows him to level up one of his skills.
Each skill has its own purpose and does its own thing, an example of a skill would be:

```
class DamageAura(Skill):
    """
    This skill increases damage dealt by your hero,
    as well as deals damage back to the ones who attack your hero.
    """

    name = 'Damage Aura'
    description = '...'

    # These methods are called when the actual event happens in game

    def unit_attack(self, target, damage):  
        target._health -= (self.level / 100) * damage

    def unit_defend(self, attacker, damage):
        attacker.deal_damage((self.level / 100) * damage)
```

Now I would like the players of the game to be able to make their own heroes, and I **need** it to be simple.
The problem is, I don't want to do "bad" code simply to make creating heroes easier.
Here's what a hero class would ideally look like:

```
class Warrior(Hero):
    name = 'Warrior'
    description = 'Ancient Warrior is thirsty for blood.'
    maximum_level = 30
    agility = 20
    intelligence = 10
    strength = 30

    class DamageAura(Skill):
        name = 'Damage Aura'
        description = '...'

        def unit_attack(...):
            ...

    class StrongerWeapons(Skill):
        name = 'Stronger Weapons'
        ...
```

Now the problem is, I'd like the `name` variable to be an attribute of the actual hero (f.e.`Warrior`) instance, not a class variable.
Is there an easy, yet safe way to merge these two?
Basically the class variables would define the default values for a hero, but if I wanted to create a `Warrior` instance with a custom name, I could do so by simply doing `warrior1 = Warrior(name='Warrior God', maximum_level=40)`

This is what the class would look like if I didn't have to worry about subclasses or ease-of-creation:

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description='', maximum_level=50, skill_set=None, ...):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.maximum_level = maximum_level
        self.skill_set = skill_set or []
        ...
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention; each player could be playing the exact same hero, Warrior in this case, so that's why Warrior is a class, not just an instance of Hero. They would all have the same skill set, but unique levels, etc.

**EDIT 2:**
I'm having no problem with Python classes or anything, normally I would NOT make the skills nested classes, or anything similar, but in this case I must invest **a lot** on ease of creating classes, so even the "noobs" can do it without knowing rarely any python at all.

Comment: Not sure if you were implying this, but `__init__` is not "bad code". It's quite commonly used.

Comment: So, you intend to let players create custom Hero classes by letting them write code, is that correct? If so, why?

Comment: Note that nested classes are very rarely a good idea in Python.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it's what *the class would look like if I didn't have to worry about subclasses or ease-of-creation*. However, it completely discards the possibility of using the "ease-of-creation" version where I define the variables on the class-level (first piece of code in my original question).

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Well, technically not players, but the server hosts. I want each server to be able to decide what their own heroes look like, this way there could be thousands of different heroes with different skill sets.

Comment: Given your requirement that *"even the "noobs" can do it without knowing rarely any python at all"*, I would strongly suggest you look at parsing the definitions from a defined file format, rather than letting them near the actual code! That's a much easier way to provide *"ease of creating classes"* than abusing OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could allow the end users to create their `Hero` definitions as a dictionary:

```
my_hero = dict(name='Warrior'.
               description='Ancient Warrior is thirsty for blood.',
               maximum_level=30,
               ...)
```

Then you can easily create an instance like:

```
hero = Hero(**my_hero)
```

*(If the syntax is unfamiliar, see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761))*

For both `DamageAura` and `Warrior`, it seems **more appropriate for them to be instances than subclasses** of `Skill` and `Hero` respectively.

---

Alternatively, consider letting the user create their characters *outside* of your code (e.g. in JSON, XML, YAML, ...), then parse the files and create appropriate instances from the input data.

Comment: Read my edit, I'm pretty sure the classes should be classes, not instances. Sorry, forgot to mention it in the first place. How would I implement the skills using your method? They'd need to be linked to the hero, and preferrably hero would be defined before skills.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen but there is no reason each player couldn't have their own `Hero` instance *without* subclassing - just create four `Hero` instances from the `Warrior` specification.

Comment: Ahh I see it now... Thanks, I think I'll use your approach!